# void function call not working c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a simple text editor. I need to use the void functions as they are listed. I cannot change the parameters. I am able to call the first void function open(file) but not the insert command. I tested the open function by printing the struct with an overloaded operator.

```
 int main() 
 {
     editor_file file;
     string command;
     string insert;

     cout << "Welcome to TextEditor. Please enter a filename: ";

     open(file);

     cout << file;
     cout << '>';
     cin >> command;


     if(command == insert)
     {   
         insert(file);  // error: no match for call to '(std::string) (editor_file&)'
     }

     cout << file;

    return 0;
}
```

void functions in separate file

```
void open(editor_file &file)
{

    string line;
    string filename; 
    ifstream fin(filename.c_str());
    do 
    {
        cin >> filename;       
        fin.open(filename.c_str());
        file.name = filename; 

        if(fin.fail())
        {
            cout << "Invalid File. ";
            cout << "Please enter another file name: ";
        }
    }while (fin.fail());

    getline(fin, line);

    while(fin)
    {
        file.data += line + '\n';
        getline(fin, line);
    }

}


void insert(editor_file &file)
{

    char character;
    cin >> character;
    string info = file.data;

    info.insert(file.cursor, character);
}
```

struct in header file

```
struct editor_file
{
    std::string name;

    std::string data;

    int cursor;

    bool is_open;

    bool is_saved;

    editor_file():cursor(0),is_open(false), is_saved(true) {}
};
```

Comment: Try renaming the string "insert" to another name that does not conflict with the function insert. Also, you never initialize your insert string with a value before using it.

Comment: Better yet, stop saying `using namespace std`.

Comment: @JohnSheridan I didn't see your comment before. Paste it as an answer, and I'll delete mine and upvote yours!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to rename your

> string insert

To something like

> string strInsert

This is because you shouldn't use the same name for both a variable and a function!

Comment: thank you! I took out the declaration and changed the if statement to if (operation == "insert")

Comment: Alternatively, leave the local variable as it is and refer to the hidden name in the global namespace as `::insert`. There's no need to invent weird naming conventions to solve a problem the language has already solved.